# javascript/Jquery code organisation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a php app where almost all requests are in ajax and some Jquery effects, so some of my pages are up to 2000 lines of code, all my jquery in one big $document.ready{}, is it normal? should I be ashamed of showing this code to other developers? or is there a better way of organasing Jquery code ?

Comment: Are you encapsulating some of the functions into an object? can you break them down into logical groups? i.e. with a `common.js` file and then each `.php` page has its own `.js` page - there are many ways to organize your code,it depends on what makes sense, really.

Comment: Is your code efficient? Does it work? Is it maintainable? If yes, that's fine. Be proud of what you have done. Other things are theories and personal preferences.

Comment: If your application is sufficiently complex, lots of lines of code is inevitable. But remember the motto "[don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)"! If you have lots of code that is copy pasted a lot, try to refactor it to avoid this.

Comment: Did you include your name in the comments, or your personal address? If so, I would expect lots of hate mail

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest using for example TypeScript for semi-large or large client-side apps. It's capable of compiling separate TS files into one big Javascript bundle, so besides every advantage of TS, there is a lot of flexibility on the code organizing part too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like how many others have said, if it's maintainable and easy to read then it shouldn't be much of an issue. However, in my experiences, code that is organized into separate logical modules were MUCH easier to read and maintain than one long document.

With that being said, the typical workflow these days with tools such as browserify would be to refactor and separate the code such that each file executes a specific task for development purposes and when it is time to deploy to production, one would use a build tool to group/minify and optimize for the browser.